# Allow Email Interaction - Java Server

Tags: java, dns, email, mail-server

First of all, this is a kinda broad question, and I believe it belongs partially on Serverfault also, so bear with me. I tried googling and searching here, but only found parts of this question but not the whole idea of it. Here goes:

My problem is:

Im writing a web application, and my server is Java. I want to add a feature where my users can do BY EMAIL some of the possible interactions they can already do on the interface. For this part I believe to setup a mail server (any server recommendations?), and from my Java app (Tomcat) connect to the mail server and read the emails via POP3 or something (any API recommendations?).

The tricky part is that I dont want to use a single email address for that purpose. I want, for example, that if my user Joe want to CREATE an object in my application, then he would send an email to joe@create.mydomain.com, if he would like to DELETE an object, he would send to joe@delete.mydomain.com. The possible actions are previously known and limited, of course (since I would have to mess with the DNS for that purpose). This is just an example, most likely I would have to "tokenize" the left part of the email address (before the @), or else any user would be able to create and delete other user´s objects (since email is semi-anonymous).

And the extra-tricky part is that I already have an email server running on mydomain.com, for the corporate emails. How to make that all emails from the actions words ("subdomains"?) go to my "application email server" and those without action words go to my "corporate email server"?

I guess thats it!

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using Java, it sounds like [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) might be a good fit for you.

It allows you to create [Matchers](http://james.apache.org/server/2.3.1/custom_matcher.html) and [Mailets](http://james.apache.org/mailet/api/index.html) which pick out and process emails based on your defined criteria (which could be address based sender/receiver matching, subject lines, etc). The process could insert records into a database, invoke a web service, anything you want to write in Java.

Comment: Seems like a great tool, would simplify a lot my planned solution (insert records into a database would be the best!). But still theres the "extra-tricky" part I have to mess a bit to see how to do it without messing the corporate email, but I think you solved the greatest part of the question :)